# Nginx block server routing

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I am trying to route a url to another part of my server - the admin area which is made by angular using nginx server blocks.

I can get it working using

```
location ~ /admin {
     root /home/sysadmin/html;
}
```

This routes to **/home/sysadmin/html/admin.index.html**. What I can't figure out is how to route all deeper URLS to this file location i.e. `/admin/dashboard/` would also go to `/home/sysadmin/html/index.html`.

For example, if go to `www.url.com/admin/` it works and my angular app runs but if I refresh on `www.url.com/admin/login` it will produce a 404.

I need all child urls of `/admin` to go to my systems `/home/sysadmin/html/admin/index.html` file.

Please note, this is a nginx issue not a angular one as I can navigate and run my project fine.

is it best to setup an alternative subdomain that points to `www.url.com/admin` and manage it another server block?

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [the Nginx try_files directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).

`location ~ /admin {
     root /home/sysadmin/html/admin;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}`

This says that it will test for the existence of the actual files or folders (relative to the root folder you specified) first, and then if none are found it will return the index.html in that root instead.

This is common when setting up HTML5 mode in Angular, for which it sounds like you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a .htaccess file and make a rewrite base

```
 # If the request is a file, folder or symlink that exists, serve it up
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [S=1]

 # otherwise, serve your index.html app
 RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.html
```

you need also config in angularJS depending ngroute or ui.router

```
 // use the HTML5 History API
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and put also a meta in head like this

```
<base href="/someappfolder/">
```

update:
I should add this for nginx configuration

```
  # nginx configuration
  location / {
  if (-e $request_filename){
  rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html;
  }
  }
```

also take a look at here http://senior-java-developer.com/html5angularjsnginx-crawlable-application/

Comment: This is a Nginx server block not htaccess. Also I currently have a working angualr version running and this is the second admin angular app. Its all routes after /admin I need. The issue is to do with the nginx server not angular.

Comment: it should be something like this
# nginx configuration
location / {
if (-e $request_filename){
rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.html;
}
}

Comment: No I am routing url.com/ADMIN to a different location on my server compared to my base angular app

Comment: have you thought of this? why don't you use templating and load the content of admin folder to here? it is only a suggestion  ;)

Comment: Yes, I  want my admin panel as a stand alone application. There is no need to deliver it to the end user who will never use it.

Comment: So I think this way it's very complicated, try to access it like a web server via ajax! this would be preferable