# laravel, how can I ignore a special route?

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

how can I ignore special routes with nginx server.
for example I have `a.com` address and I want Ignore `a.com/abc`

Comment: @RandoHinn  my question is for ngnix not for Appache ! duplicate :|

Comment: In that case look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677956/nginx-block-server-routing) question instead.

Comment: This snippet is working for me to avoid any request. I written in top of routes.php 

Route::get('/{anyString}', function () {
    if(Request::url() == 'abc'){
        return App::abort(404);
    }
});

Comment: By "ignore" do you mean that Laravel shouldn't respond to the route and there should be a 404? Or do you mean that nginx should not run it through Laravel at all, and do something else with it?

Comment: This code will display 404 page. If you want to fix it with Laravel you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `try_files` in your Nginx config like so, the web server will first see if the file exists and return it if it does; otherwise it will send the request to Laravel's `index.php` front controller letting the framework decide what to do with it:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

Should you want to do something totally different with a specified directory, you can do the following (you don't specify in your question what you'd like  your special route to do):

```
location /abc {
    // Fulfil special request
}
```